# How to prevent others from using my REST API?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, security

I've developed simple REST API using a expressJs. I'm using React as my client side application. So the problem is anyone can see my API endpoints because of react app is in client side. So they will also able to make request and fetch data from my REST API. (May be they will build their own client side apps using my API.) I've seen some question about this and couldn't find any comprehensive answer. How these kind of a security problem should be handled? Is it possible to give the access for API to only my client app? If not how huge brands that using REST API prevent that? (Also I don't have a user authenticating scenario in my product as well. People can just visit and use the website. They don't need to register).

Comment: So act on that very last sentence you have in parentheses: add user authentication to your system. The scenario you're sketching is one that is solved by making sure that connections with the right credentials (e.g via an API key/auth token, not by transmitting a user/pass each time) allowed permitted, and everyone else gets a 403.

Comment: As you said, having an authentication step would be already a first step, so only authenticated client could request the API

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans In my case users don't need to register into my system. They can visit and use the website. What about then?

Comment: Then you add that to your post and the answer is "make sure to set up proper CORS and CSP rules", and you also make sure that only connections with an active session (so even without auth: use session management) get API responses.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks.  I'll looking into that.

Comment: For CORS, express makes its own library (see https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html), for CSP, and lots of other security layers like HSTS, XSS filtering, etc, you typically use [helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet).

Comment: to OP, its not possible to protect an API without authentication. Why? Server-side code does not adhere to CORS or CSP, one could make a simple 2 or 3 line proxy to bypass CORS

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Then can't we have a REST API for a website where users don't need to register to use it? (Let's say for example movies website. People can just visit website and see movie posts. No need to register. Isn't it possible to have a secure REST API in this case?)

Comment: as said no. Imagin you added sessions which then had a single use token, then a scrapper script could fetch the token first, imaging you had cookies or some other token, then a scrapper could scrap it first, imaging you needed to login then a scrapper could login first. If your API is wide open the is nothing you can do except lookup IP address can compare it with a list of known hosting providers, count usage from single IPs, i.e one IP seems to be making 100k per day and is logging into multiple accounts, or if no account then is using multiple single use tokens at once etc.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone But let's say I have authentication system. Also someone can create client side app and use that registration endpoints to register users. Then again they can use my API. Isn't it? I'm bit confused with all these things :~)

Comment: Clientside app hitting your API directly is different, CORS will protect that, but there is nothing you can do to protect from something like [`app.use('/his-api', proxy('https://yoursite.com'))`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy) or a custom script which does logic on the path, i.e `/login`, `/register` does a call using node-fetch to your API to login/register, then pipes the headers and all that good stuff to the client. Protecting from scrapping can really only be done by detecting if the IP is a scrapper though IP location or abuse like one IP has signed up 100x etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

If, as you state in your comment, this is about users on your own website being allowed to use your site's API, while disallowing off-site use (e.g. other websites, `wget`/`curl`, etc) then you need to make sure to set up proper CORS rules (to disallowed cross-origin use of your API) as well as CSP rules (to prevent user-injected scripts from proxying your API), and you also need to make sure to only allow API calls from connections that have an active session (so even if you don't want user authentication: use a session managemer so you can tell if someone landed on your site and got a session cookie set before they started calling API endpoints).

Session management and CORS come with express itself (see https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html and https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html), for CSP, and lots of other security layers like HSTS, XSS filtering, etc, you typically use [helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet).

Answer (score 1):

Authentication can be a way but it can be bypassed. Another way is you can create a proxy server which strictly blocks cross origin requests, hence it blocks requests from other domains to make request to your API, and you can make your API call from that proxy server. In this way your API server endpoint will also be not compromised.